# OpenGL ES on iPhone doesn't draw anything

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, opengl-es

I'm an absolute beginner in OpenGL ES programming in iOS.

This is my first attempt to draw some simple 2D primitives with OpenGL ES onto a view.

Here is the class declaration:

```
@interface OGLGameCanvas : UIView <GameCanvas> {
    EAGLContext* context;
    Game* game;
    GLuint framebuffer, renderbuffer, depthbuffer;
}
```

Here is my initialization code:

```
- (void)initialize {

    // Get the layer and set properties

    CAEAGLLayer* layer = (CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer;

    layer.opaque = NO;
    layer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];


    // Set the context

    context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

    if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context])
        DLog(@"Cannot create EAGLContext!");


    // Create the color buffer and the render buffer

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderbuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer);

    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)layer];
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer);

    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        NSLog(@"Failed to make complete frame buffer: %x", status);


    // Get width and height of the render buffer

    GLint width, height;
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &width);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &height); 

    // Create and start animation loop

    CADisplayLink* displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(drawFrame:)];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}
```

and my drawing code:

```
- (void)drawFrame:(CADisplayLink*)sender {

    glLoadIdentity();
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    GLfloat vertices[] = { -20.0f, 2.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.5f, 7.5f };
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glPointSize(5.0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 3);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];

}
```

The canvas gets cleared (in fact, it becomes black, or red, or whatever I set into glClearColor), but no points are drawn.

I'm pretty sure I'm forgetting something basic and essential.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = { -20.0f, 2.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.5f, 7.5f };
```

The normalized device coordinates lay in range [-1..1] so you're drawing them outside the visible area.

And here:

You have to do this before drawing.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Comment: Thanks. Moving my first steps... I still don't understand the whole concept behind transformation matrices. I play with them but, for example, I can't focus the concept of "device coordinates"...

Comment: Well you really just need time and practice to understand all of that stuff. I suggest you to start from understanding the math, cause it's crucial for graphics. Read this book: http://books.google.com/books/about/Mathematics_for_3D_game_programming_and.html?id=bfcLeqRUsm8C